# Classic ASP - Check the length of a number

Tags: asp-classic

Is there a way to check the length of a number in classic asp

for instance 1 = 1 number ... 196 = 3 numbers ... 10 = 2 numbers

When i try

```
Len(number)
```

It always returns 1

Any help would be great.

Cheers

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
Len(cstr(number))
```

should do the trick

Answer (score 0):

`Len` checks the length of **strings**.

Apparently it doesn't work correctly when you pass a number.

Try converting the number to a string and passing **that** to `Len`:

```
Len(CStr(number))
```

---

*Disclaimer: this is out of my head - don't have an ASP Classic environment here to test it)*

Answer (score 0):

i just tested

```
dim number
number = 12345
response.write(len(number))
response.write(len(cstr(number)))
```

it returns 5 on both cases...